# OpenGL points drawn disappear, draw call and swap buffer issue?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am wanting to draw points on screen from the vertex data already sent to the GPU using GL_POINTS. At the moment they are drawn for a split second and then disappear. I am using a time-dependent loop as I want the points to appear sequentially...

```
if (currentTime > insertionRateTime)
{
    cout << "insertionRateTime = " << insertionRateTime << "index" << index << endl;
    insertionRateTime += insertionRate;
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, index, 1); 
    index += 1;
}

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

Can anybody shed any light here? If I place the glDrawArrays outside of the if statement then the points drawn remain until the next point is drawn :(

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: Your problem sounds very similar to particle system using point sprites. Have look at them.

Comment: If you want the points to appear over time and never disappear, then place the glDrawArrays outside of the loop and increase the count instead of the start.

Comment: Thank you BDL!!! The issue here was exactly that - I was increasing the start whilst incrementing the index...doh! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by increasing the 'count' argument in glDrawArrays as suggested by BDL in the comments! Thanks!